# Config the server uses netty 4 has 20,000 client's connection

Tags: java, asynchronous, server, netty, nio

I'm using netty 4.0 to write TCP server, it may be 20k client load simultaneously. But my sever not withstand many such connections.
This is my code.

```
private void initServer(){
EventLoopGroup boosGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(100);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1000);
EventExecutorGroup eegHandle = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1000);
EventExecutorGroup eegDecode = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1000);
EventExecutorGroup eegEndcode = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1000);
try {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(boosGroup, workerGroup);
        bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeLine = ch.pipeline();
                //add check idle time of connection
                pipeLine.addLast("Ilde event", new IdleStateHandler(timeIdleRead, timeIdleWrite, 0));
                //add idle handler to handle idle connection
                pipeLine.addLast("Idle handler", new ServerHandleIdleTime(logger));
                //add decode handler to decode message received from client
                pipeLine.addLast(eegDecode, new ServerMsgDecoder());
                //add business handler to process business
                pipeLine.addLast(eegHandle, new ServerHandleSimple());
                //add encode handler to encode message send to client
                pipeLine.addFirst(eegEncode, new ServerMsgEncoder());
            }
        });
        bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 200);
        bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false);
        // bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(host, port);
        channelFuture.sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        boosGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }}
```

Should I use 3 for 3 handler EventExecutorGroup like that?.
I used nthread(= 1000) for workerGroup have sufficient for 20k connection?.
I wish the help of everyone to reconfigure the server.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

NIO does not imply to have as many threads as connected clients, but as many active clients (incoming or outgoing message), at least if you want them to be parallel.

Else, if maximum parallelism is not willing, then you will wait a bit between each message (each thread will go from one channel to another as soon as possible). In general, that's not an issue.

However I think 1000 is quite a lot already. But it may really depend on your needs. 1000 for 20K clients, means that at the same time, at most 5% of clients are really active (even if they are connected). If your clients are connected AND really active, 1000 could be not enough... If your clients send let say 1 message per second and each message takes 100 ms, then it implies in average 10% of concurrent messages, so 2000... You have to figure it yourself.

On your `EventExecutorGroup`, it depends on your **encoder and decoder and business** handlers:

- If one is blocking or long time spending, then a `EventExecutorGroup` might be needed for this one.
- If not, then no need for such `EventExecutorGroup`.

You might try also the following:

- Increasing if necessary the number of treads to the number of probable active (or concurrent) messages in codec and business handlers, and also in workerGroup.
- Using the same `EventExecutorGroup` for several handlers.
- Add `ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR` to true in your bootstrap.
- bossGroup should be in general up to (2 x number of core) +1  (so if you have a 6 core, you could set it to 13). There should not be such a need to increase it to 100.
- Make the order of your handler more align with usual practice:

  1. IdleStateHandler
  2. ServerHandleIdleTime
  3. ServerMsgDecoder
  4. ServerMsgEncoder // currently in first position in your code due to addFirst
  5. ServerHandleSimple

Comment: If it helps you, please valid the answear such that next readers could follow it. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
My clients sends a message to server for each 10s. At some time may be shorter.
I have configured for workerGroup to 2000 thread. Put EventExecutorGroup has 3000 thread for encoder and decoder and business handlers. Set ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR is true.
Now I have a range of 10,000 new connections, but according to my log, some proactive client closed connection (ERROR: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host). As far as I understand, the server can not meet the new should happen this situation.
I have not found a way to solve this problem.

Comment: @dovuvnd I believe the workerGroup and EventExecutorGroup could have the same size (if I understand, you put 2000 for the first and 3000 for the second). For the next part of your problem, I believe this is a different issue since not related to ability to have 20K clients. So please open a new one with more details and valid this one. ;-)

Comment: Maybe my problem is to configure the server so effective. 
You can share some ideas and experience as my problem, aren't you?.
ps: My english is not good. wish you sympathize